# Как подключить звуковое оповещение в python?

Tags: python, аудио

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой звуковой модуль или встроенную функцию лучше использовать и как её применять.
Например мне нужно, чтобы после достижения определённого условия происходил сигнал.
Например:

```py
data = (5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3, 8)
for i in data:
    if i >= 8:
        # Звуковой сигнал
```

Недавно я пробовал подключить звуковой скрипт, но при исполнении звукового сигнала сначала открывалось звуковое приложение отдельной вкладкой, только потом проигрывал звук. Мне этот вариант не понравился. Есть варианты, где бы мелодия или звук в python отрабатывали без посторонних приложений? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537481/python-making-a-beep-noise

Comment: Почему то ничего не происходит... Звук не издаётся                                                                                                                                                       
import winsound
data = (5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3)
for i in data:
    if i == 8:
        frequency = 250  
        duration = 1000 
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows можно посмотреть модуль `winsound` (входит в стандартную библиотеку).

Comment: Пробовал подключить, но почему то ничего не происходит. import winsound
data = (5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3)
for i in data:
    if i == 8:
        frequency = 250  
        duration = 1000 
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)

Comment: У меня ваш код нормально запускается и слышно звук. У вас звук-то не выключен?

Comment: Если что я запускал такой код:

`import winsound
data = (5, 6, 7, 3, 5 , 8, 3)
for i in data:
    if i == 8:
        frequency = 250
        duration = 1000
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
`

Comment: @VladimirChistov пример кода лучше добавить в сам ответ.

Comment: Странно, я тоже самое запускаю, но звука всё равно нет. Звук включен на всю. Музыка с вк играет. Может проблема в самом редакторе кода? Я использую Visual Studio.  А у вас какой редактор кода?

Comment: У меня Sublime Text

Comment: Попробуйте из cmd ввести команду `python имя_файла.py`

Answer (score 0):

Можно через pygame mixer (pip install pygame):

```
import pygame as pg
pg.mixer.init()
pg.mixer.music.load("путь до файла (начиная от этой папки)")
data = (5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8)
for i in data:
    if i >= 8:
        pg.mixer.music.play()  # что-бы остоновить использовать pg.mixer.music.stop()
```

Если надо ждать пока идет звук то вот этот код (pip install eyed3):

```
import pygame as pg
import time
import eyed3
pg.mixer.init()
pg.mixer.music.load("путь до файла (начиная от этой папки)")
data = (5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8)
for i in data:
    if i >= 8:
        pg.mixer.music.play()  # что-бы остоновить использовать pg.mixer.music.stop()
        time.sleep(eyed3.load("путь до файла (начиная от этой папки)").info.time_secs)
```

*Все эти библиотеки не входят в стандартную

Answer (score 0):

Для стандартных звуков из темы Linux
https://py-canberra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

```
import canberra
canberra.play(event_id='bell')
```